# How to restrict <input type="file"> so that it can only select .pdf files?

Tags: html, pdf, file-io

By default it can select all type of files,how to restrict it so that it can only select `.pdf` files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML file input field with limited file types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240934/html-file-input-field-with-limited-file-types)

Comment: Client side this is not possible AFAIK. You'll need to check @ server side what exactly the user decided to post.

Comment: Check also [File input 'accept' attribute - is it useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/) for workarounds.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the [accept](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-accept) attribute on your form to suggest to the browser to restrict certain types.  However, you'll want to re-validate in your server-side code to make sure.  Never trust what the client sends you.

Answer (score 80):

more explicitly...

```
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf" />
```

Comment: Why is this NOT working when the PC has no Adobe Reader installed? Happened to me today...

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: you can't using the plain html and javascript. The closest you can get is to test the file extension using javascript before submitting the form and show some error message to the user if it is other than `.pdf`. You might need to use some client side solution such as Flash upload controls if you want to achieve this.

Comment: You can't use JavaScript to drop the file based on its extension?

Comment: @Šime Vidas, yes indeed javascript could be used to test the extension of the selected file.