# Is there a way to restrict your input element to only accept videos?

Tags: reactjs, video

I have an input element with type set to file which I am using to upload files. The problem is it also accepts images but I don't want that. I only want videos to be accepted. Is there a way to go about it?

```
 <input
   type="file"
   id="file"
   ref={inputFile}
   onChange={(event) => handleVideoUpload(event.target.files[0])}
      }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML file input field with limited file types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240934/html-file-input-field-with-limited-file-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#unique_file_type_specifiers) prop

If required an extra step to validate -
you can check the condition before submitting / posting by using [File type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type) - MIME of `video`

a sample e.g.

```js
const { useRef } = React;

const App = () => {
  const fileRef = useRef(null);
  
  const handleVideoUpload = (file) => {
    if(!file.type.includes("video")){
      alert("not a video and don't submit, just return")
      return
    }else{
      alert("It's a video ... proceed submitting")
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="file"
        id="file"
        accept="video/*"
        ref={fileRef}
        onChange={(event) => handleVideoUpload(event.target.files[0])}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: i have done this but what i need is when user browses on their computer to upload file they can only select video files. is this possible?

Comment: edited please check ... yeah I thought just validating my bad :|

Comment: special tnx! resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The *accept* attribute on the input should do the job:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept