# Get Image height before its fully loaded

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to use jQuery to get the height of an image `#imageHero` before it has fully loaded into the page. I then need to set the height of a div `#imageDiv` to be the height of the `#imageHero` which is being loaded.

I need this to happen ASAP when the page is created... currently the code I am using to set the div `#imageDiv` to the height of the image `#imageDiv` is happening to slowly and the page load looks odd...

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get image dimensions with Javascript before image has fully loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575159/get-image-dimensions-with-javascript-before-image-has-fully-loaded)

Comment: Thanks A Wolff - I saw that, but no solution was given in code terms - just that jFiddle... i was hoping for a little more support...

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't know any other way. If any, I would like to know it too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575159/get-image-dimensions-with-javascript-before-image-has-fully-loaded), although in pure JavaScript not JQuery. I have adapted that answer to:

- Use JQuery
- Work with a static image
- Created a simple function that you can call

Here's the function...

```
function getImageSize(img, callback){
    img = $(img);

    var wait = setInterval(function(){        
        var w = img.width(),
            h = img.height();

        if(w && h){
            done(w, h);
        }
    }, 0);

    var onLoad;
    img.on('load', onLoad = function(){
        done(img.width(), img.height());
    });


    var isDone = false;
    function done(){
        if(isDone){
            return;
        }
        isDone = true;

        clearInterval(wait);
        img.off('load', onLoad);

        callback.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

You can call the function with an image element, and a callback accepting width and height arguments...

```
getImageSize($('#imageHero'), function(width, height){
    $('#imageDiv').height(height);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcyLh/2/) - To see the full effect make sure the image is not in your cache (append a random to the image source).

Comment: Thanks - will see if this way works - how would I get the function to work on y #imageHero image?

Comment: @dubbs I've updated the snippet at the bottom of my answer, it shows the code for your image.

Comment: OK thanks. I still have the issue that the #imageDiv is not resized instantly when the page loads... could this be due to position of jQuery calls on the page itself?

Comment: @dubbs Can you post some code, just the HTML containing the image and it's containers.

Comment: Actually - its seems to be working really nicely - I placed the function and call inline in the HTML so as to make it load quicker and does the job pretty well // thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

An improvement on [@Drahcir's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390393/get-image-height-before-its-fully-loaded#23391387) answer, this version returns the true height and has other improvements. For testing change `abc123` in image source to any random string to prevent caching.

There is a [JSFiddle  Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ct1wtktm/) as well.

```
<div id="info"></div>
<img id="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/Island_Archway,_Great_Ocean_Rd,_Victoria,_Australia_-_Nov_08.jpg?abc123">

<script>
getImageSize($('#image'), function(width, height) {
    $('#info').text(width + ',' + height);
});

function getImageSize(img, callback) {
    var $img = $(img);

    var wait = setInterval(function() {
        var w = $img[0].naturalWidth,
            h = $img[0].naturalHeight;
        if (w && h) {
            clearInterval(wait);
            callback.apply(this, [w, h]);
        }
    }, 30);
}
</script>
```