# Get image height and then show

Tags: jquery

I want to load the image, determine the height, and THEN show it

Here is my code:

```
$("#block").animate({
        height: HERE GOES HEIGHT + 50px for additional space
    },
    function() {
        $("img").fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

Comment: How would the system be able to determine the height before it was loaded?  You could possibly load the image, determine the height, and THEN show it (fade in, or whatever you need).  I think that's the best way.

Comment: Yup. "load the image, determine the height, and THEN show it" That is what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work?

```
$("img").load(function(){
var imgHeight = $(this).height();
});

$("#block").animate({
    height: '+='imgHeight
},
function() {
    $("img").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Grabbing the image dimensions before the page is loaded is not something I think is particularly possible like this.

However there is a similar post to grab the image dimensions before its fully loaded, then you could tie that into your animation.

[Get image dimensions with Javascript before image has fully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575159/get-image-dimensions-with-javascript-before-image-has-fully-loaded)