# jQuery gets the image height before the image is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have looked around and tried many solutions, but jquery still tries to get the image height before the image is loaded:

```
$('img').load(function(){
    var heightStart = $(".carousel .carousel-inner img").height();
    alert(heightStart); // 0
});
```

I always get an **0**. Any ideas what is the best way of doing this?

I even have tried with the plain js:

```
    var i = new Image()
    i.src = "images/xxx.jpg";
    var h = i.height
    alert(heightStart); // 464
```

It gets the image height but the number is wrong! The number is always smaller but the image has a long height.

**EDIT:**

the images have not height and width attributes:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">

        <img class="first-slide" src="images/xxx.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">xxx</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My image height is `464` so `new Image()` is **correct**. but the problem is that the image has been resized on the large screen with `img-responsive`.

Comment: Call me crazy but for the first part, shouldn't it be `$(".carousel .carousel-inner img").load`? If you just do `$('img')`, it will call the function even when the first image on the page loads, not just that specific image. Of course, I can't see your HTML, maybe it is the only image on the page...

Comment: guys, please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: Is that all your question about what your title means? If so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575319/1414562

Comment: @A.Wolff have tried that answer. but still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('img').load(function(){
    alert($(this).height());
});
```

or

```
var i = new Image()
i.src = "images/xxx.jpg";
i.onload = function() { alert(this.height) };
```

A little explanation to go with the answer - your first function registers onload listeners to *all* present `img` elements that alerts the first matched `img` element within `.carousel .carousel-inner`'s height, which might be 0, who knows.

The problem with your vanilla example is that you are trying to alert the height before the image is done loading.

Comment: @teelou I don't understand what the problem is?