# Add a filetype validation to phpmailer?

Tags: php, file-upload, validation, phpmailer

I have a phpmailer that attaches files by looping through an array of files from an file input field. How can i make it so that onl PDF or DOC are allowed. And if something else is attempted, the script stope and gives an error: "File type not supported. Only PDF or DOC."

Any suggestions? Heres my current script;

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['files']['name']) as $key) {
        $source = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);
}
```

Comment: How is your question related to phpmailer? Isn't the question how to validate a filetype with PHP?

Comment: @hakre Well I need to validate before using a phpmailer function AddAttachment..

Comment: There was a similar question some time ago, maybe it's helpful: [phpMailer attachment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322610/phpmailer-attachment/6322645).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at $_FILES['files']['type'] and make sure it matches the mime types you want.

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    if ($file['files']['type'] == 'application/msword' 
        || $file['files']['type'] == 'application/pdf'
    ) { 
        $source = $file['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $filename = $file['files']['name'][$key];
        $mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);
    }
    else {
        die("You may only upload PDF and Microsoft Word documents through this form.");
    }
}
```

Comment: And then how do i add a 'quit and error message' sorta thing to the else statement? (New to php..)

Comment: is it `else {
  die("File type not supported. Only PDF or DOC");
  }` ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer to reflect this. However you may not want to abruptly quit like that. Generally it is better to throw an exception and then handle it.

Comment: Actually I just discovered a slight problem.. Your if is located outside the foreach statement, so no matter what it reverts to the else and die

Comment: I've added a `foreach()` statement for you. There is no need to do `array_keys()` if you're not using it. `$_FILES` is already an array.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the followup