# how to valdate .xls file in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to validate the file format.

How can i allow the user to upload only .xls file in jquery.

I am using uploadfy plugin to upload the file

Regards
showreddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question was answered up top, you can bind a submit function to check the file by performing this below ->

```
$("#my_form").bind("submit", function(){
  var ext = $('#my_file_field').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  if($.inArray(ext, ['xls']) == -1) {
    alert('invalid extension!');
  }
});
```

This question was asked previously over at ->

[How to have jQuery restrict file types on upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651700/how-to-have-jquery-restrict-file-types-on-upload)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the option of uploadfy `'fileExt' : '*.xls'`

- http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/fileext/

But there is no way you can validate a file, that you are currently uploading to the server.