# Find Filetype and Filesize before Upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, filesize, file-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have jQuery restrict file types on upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651700/how-to-have-jquery-restrict-file-types-on-upload)

I have a question.
I will send a form via Ajax. This form can also send files too. 
how can I find up what file type is selected and how large the file is.
I know that you can do it with FILE API in HTML5  but it doesnt work in Internet Explorer 7,8 and 9.
Have you any idea how can I find out the file type and file size before upload.

I will also dont use any plugins.
I will a way that you program something yourself

Comment: possible dublicate of  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651700/how-to-have-jquery-restrict-file-types-on-upload]

Comment: Do you check the post data in ajax?

Comment: Heloo muthu yes i will check data in ajax

Answer (score 0):

[Here a good tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). ajax upload doesnt work with < IE 8 if you not use flash uploader