# jQuery validation extension upload file type

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-validate

I have this to upload files and get a progress bar. I'd like to restrict the uploaded file to only pdf, unfortunately it doesn't work with JQuery validation plug-in with this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('#up-form').validate({
 rules: {
     uploadedfile: {
         required: true,
         accept: "application/pdf",
         },
     },
 messages: {
    uploadedfile: "File must be PDF",
    },
 highlight: function(element) {
     $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
 },
 success: function(element) {
 element
     .addClass('valid')
     .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
 }
});


$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {


        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
     bar.width("100%");
    percent.html("100%");
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 
})();
```

how can i fix that ? For each file i try to upload, i always have the error message "File must be PDF".

I also verify the extension on the server-side but to save bandwith, i'd like to make it also client-side

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try the suggestion in the link. It might work for what you're trying to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651700/how-to-have-jquery-restrict-file-types-on-upload

Comment: I used this `$("#up-form").bind("submit", function() { 
        var ext = $('#uploadedfile').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if($.inArray(ext, ['pdf']) == -1) {
            alert('invalid extension!');
        }
    });` when i try to upload an other file than pdf, it show me the alert but it upload the file

Comment: you've done nothing to connect the 2 plugins. docs for both have examples for working together. Without recognizing validation, form plugin will submit regardless of it

Comment: @charlietfl : how can i do that ? sorry for asking this but i'm starting in javascript/jquery

Comment: look at examples for both plugins in their docs... suggest using `submitHandler` option within validation plugin to call the form plugin

Comment: I think i'm not so far with this : [http://jsfiddle.net/Y47Yp/](http://jsfiddle.net/Y47Yp/) Except that i'm redirect to form action url, even if i try to upload not pdf files

Comment: You have't even included the plugins in your jsFiddle.  See the "External Resources" panel on the left.

Comment: There is no such callback named `beforeSend` for the `ajaxForm` plugin.  I think you meant `beforeSubmit`.  See:  http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misspelled `beforeSubmit` as `beforeSend` which is [not a valid callback function/option for this plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object).

Then see this other answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15324504/594235

Basically, use the [`beforeSubmit` callback function of the `ajaxForm` plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object) to first programmatically check the form's validity using the [Validate plugin's `.valid()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid).

My answer assumes that your `.validate()` and `.ajaxForm()` initialization code is otherwise correct.

Added `.valid()` into the `beforeSubmit` callback of `ajaxForm()` below...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('#up-form').validate({
        rules: {
            uploadedfile: {
                required: true,
                accept: "application/pdf",
            },
        },
        messages: {
            uploadedfile: "File must be PDF",
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });


    $('#up-form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
            return $('#up-form').valid(); // TRUE when form is valid, FALSE will cancel submit
        },
        uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function (xhr) {
            bar.width("100%");
            percent.html("100%");
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try in rules

```
extension: "pdf"
```

don't forget to call

```
<script src="jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```