# Show custom text for applied file type filters on file dialog to upload particular category of files

Tags: html, file, file-upload

The following will allow users to select only specified category of image files.

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="file" size="30" 
       accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif"
/>
```

But, the problem is it would show "Custom Files" as file description in the file dialog which will confuse users about what type of file they should select.

[image: filedialogbottom]

My question is: Is there a better way I can modify the text "Custom Files" to "Image Files"

Note: If I provide "image/*" that would show "Image Files" in file description, but I DO NOT WANT TO ALLOW user to select ALL types of image files, just wanna restrict to specified formats.

Thanks for your opinion in advance.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## The short answer

As I expected it turns out this is **not possible**. The `<input type="file" />` is one of the most protected browser elements and hence least adaptable browser elements around. The reason for that browsers handle file inputs with so much care is because they wouldn't want to risk attackers accessing your files (even seeing your folder structure would be bad).

## The long answer

You might not be able to freely change the text visible in the filter box, but there is hope. In fact, in some situations it is possible to kind of choose the text that appears. One big drawback is that this is totally **not browser-compatible** and probably not **OS-compatible**.

There is also another reason why it might be a bad idea for browsers to allow editing that text, it could be used to mislead users (for example a text like `We're watching you` or `FATAL WINDOWS ERROR` could scare users).

Furthermore it should not, but could lead to possible exploits where users try to run some sort of C-code in the field (e.g. by trying to trigger some out of bounds writes), granting them machine access, possibly harming your computer in catastrophic ways. Most browsers implement the `open file window` through calling native operating system functions or ABI's, hence extra care is needed, because these instances of ABI calls could lead to sandbox escapes and/or kernel exploits. Usually it is a good idea to keep user input as far away as possible from kernel calls as possible and that is exactly what browser vendors do in this case (e.g. [hardcoded in firefox source code](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/uriloader/exthandler/nsExternalHelperAppService.cpp#533) and [hardcoded](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chromeos/chromeos_strings.grd;drc=9547605e7172c743904ca2976767d356bed5de85;l=349) in [chrome source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:ash/webui/media_app_ui/media_app_ui.cc;drc=96fdb964afaa7f93cdd09f3319da4addd805a990;l=27)).

Above I said that it is somewhat possible to change the visible filter-text. Below I handle some of the things I tried, but don't hesitate to try this for yourself on this codepen I created for testing purposes: https://codepen.io/JohannesB/pen/vKGoyE

Possible inspiration for other file-types I did not test (feel free to edit this post): https://stackoverflow.com/a/14839673/1493235

Selection of file accept-parameters that I believe could yield intresting results: **application/msword, application/rtf, application/octet-stream, application/octet-stream exe, application/zip, text/css, text/html, text/plain**

## Notable conclusions

- All three browsers **differ** in the file types associated with `image/*`, `video/*` and `audio/*`
- Internet explorer is the only browser that understands `Video/x-msvideo avi`
- Firefox and chrome understand `Aplication/pdf` with a custom filter text, but IE does noet.
- Chrome is the only browser that understand `Text/*` and that has a custom text caption for `.exe`
- **Custom filter captions never apply for combined accept inputs**, in absolutely none of the browser.

## A path not investigated

It might be possible that for flash uploaders this text is customizable, but I highly doubt it. Also, flash is deprecated, so in my opinion it's not worth trying.

---

## The experiment results

*Disclaimer: The examples used below were run on a Windows 7 machine, using Internet Explorer v11.0.9600, Chrome v51.0.2704.84m and Firefox v46.0.1. I cannot guarantee that they represent correct information on other operating systems, other browser versions or even the same browser versions. Use this information with care.*

---

## Internet explorer

**Audio/***

[image: IE Audio/*]

**Application/***

[image: IE Application/*]

**Application/pdf**

[image: IE Application/pdf]

**Image/***

[image: IE Image/*]

**Text/***

[image: IE Text/*]

**Video/***

[image: IE Video/*]

**Video/x-msvideo avi**

[image: IE Video/x-msvideo avi]

**.exe**

[image: IE .exe]

**Image/*, Video/***

[image: IE Image/, Video/]

**Image/*, .exe**

[image: IE Image/*, .exe]

---

## Chrome

**Audio/***

[image: Chrome Audio/*]

**Application/***

[image: Chrome Application/*]

**Application/pdf**

[image: Chrome Application/pdf]

**Image/***

[image: Chrome Image/*]

**Text/***

[image: Chrome Text/*]

**Video/***

[image: Chrome Video/*]

**Video/x-msvideo avi**

[image: Chrome Video/x-msvideo avi]

**.exe**

[image: Chrome .exe]

**Image/*, Video/***

[image: Chrome Image/, Video/]

**Image/*, .exe**

[image: Chrome Image/*, .exe]

---

## Mozilla Firefox

**Audio/***

[image: Mozilla Firefox Audio/*]

**Application/***

[image: Mozilla Firefox Application/*]

**Application/pdf**

[image: Mozilla Firefox Application/pdf]

**Image/***

[image: Mozilla Firefox Image/*]

**Text/***

[image: Mozilla Firefox Text/*]

**Video/***

[image: Mozilla Firefox Video/*]

**Video/x-msvideo avi**

[image: Mozilla Firefox Video/x-msvideo avi]

**.exe**

[image: Mozilla Firefox .exe]

**Image/*, Video/***

[image: Mozilla Firefox Image/, Video/]

**Image/*, .exe**

[image: Mozilla Firefox Image/*, .exe]

Comment: Very well researched, indeed helpful for someone falling in my situation. Thanks a ton for sharing!