# Check file extension before importing file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement where I have to import a file from the local using javascript jquery.
Depending on the type of file that user has selected the displaying logic is used. 
The flow is such:
User selects on 'Import' and selects the file from local. As soon as he says okay I need to retrieve the file extension that has been selected and depending on that need to display the file.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the plunker working code](http://plnkr.co/edit/FN94CWIgYpB63f9PrQSk?p=preview)

You will be getting the mime type which is the safest way to check. I just made the alert box of mime type of the code.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>


<script>
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
alert('To check whether i am getting into the script '); //Comment this
var file = this.files[0];
name = file.name;
size = file.size;
type = file.type;
alert(type);
//your validation
});
</script>
```

Credits : [Goes To](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651700/how-to-have-jquery-restrict-file-types-on-upload)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the below script Check file extension 
     
     var file_name="file.jepg";
     var extension = /.(\w+)$/.exec(file_name)[1];
     if(extension=="condition")
    {

```
}
```